# What is the difference between ::: and :::.() in scala

Tags: scala

In the scala list class it is shown that:

`List(1, 2) ::: List(3, 4) = List(3, 4).:::(List(1, 2)) = List(1, 2, 3, 4)`.
Shouldn't:

`List(1,2) ::: List(3,4) = List(1,2).:::(List(3,4)) = List(3,4,1,2)`

( method `:::` prefixes the list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List):

```
def :::(prefix: List[A]): List[A]
```

[use case]
Adds the elements of a given list in front of this list.

Example:

```
List(1, 2) ::: List(3, 4) = List(3, 4).:::(List(1, 2)) = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

In Scala, operators that end in `:` are right associative and the invoking object appears on the right side of the operator. Because it is right associative, the `prefix` method will be called on the object "to the right", which is `List(3, 4)`.

Then it will do what its name says, it will prefix `List(3, 4)` with `List(1, 2)`, and that's why you get `List(1, 2, 3 ,4)`. Not the most intuitive thing in the world but it's like this:

```
a ::: b
// ending in :, so flip the argument order, call the method on b.
b .:: a // :: = prefix b with a
result = a(concatenated) with b
```

Now let's look at the right hand side:

```
List(3, 4).:::(List(1, 2))
```

The `.` dot is performing an inversion of the `:::` prefixed invocation, so it will simply invert the two `List` objects before performing the `:::` prefix operation.

```
List(3, 4).:::(List(1,2)) = List(1, 2) ::: List(3, 4) // exactly as the above.
// and now you it's the same story.
```

The `.` dot is a simply way to invert associative operators. `a ::: b is the same as b .::: a`

Comment: Thanks, Clarified things for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are doing with 
List(1,2).:::(List(3,4)) is changing the order of things.

Ending with : makes scala want to call the method on the object to the right.
So

```
a :: b
```

is really

```
b.::(a)
```

When being explicit with the dots and parentheses, you change the order.

Not sure if this example makes it clearer:

```
scala> class X() {
     def `a:`(s: String): Unit = {
     println(s)
  }}

scala> var x = new X()
scala> x.`a:`("X")
X
scala> x `a:` "X"
<console>:10: error: value a: is not a member of java.lang.String
          x `a:` "X"
            ^
```

You see that scala wants to call the  `a:` method on the string object on the right.